# Leaving a pedal in a cross threaded state

Tags: pedals

I have a Kona Jake (specs [here](http://2015.konaworld.com/jake.cfm)) with Shimano M520 pedals and I noticed that one of my pedals wasn't quite all the trough the crank arm compared to the other pedal, see images below:

[image: Good Pedal]
[image: Bad Pedal]

The difference isn't much but I tried to tighten and then tried to remove the pedal (2nd image) but found it stuck.  Nearest I can tell, it's either cross threaded or some type of galvanized bonding took place.  However, my gut is leaning toward cross threading as I did use an anti-seize compound ([Park Tool ASC-1](https://www.parktool.com/product/anti-seize-compound-asc-1)) before originally installing the pedals.

My question is not on how to remove the pedal but the dangers or complications I might encounter if I leave the pedal as is. Please note, I don't have the problem with the pedal placement nor is there any play or free movement in the pedal at all.  And I am worried about prematurly damaging the crank arms if I force the pedal out.

It's also important to note that the pedals have been installed for just over a year at this point.  Also, when trying to remove the pedal I used a [filzer pedal tool](https://www.mec.ca/en/product/5021-719/Pedal-Wrench-PW-3) but didn't use penetraiting oil or anything like that.

So again, what are the dangers or complications I could encounter if I leave the pedal in it's current state?

Thank you kindly,

Comment: If it's cross-threaded the damage is already done, though it may take awhile for it to become apparent.  But you do understand that the pedals have opposite threads, right?  The left pedal is "backwards".

Comment: Of course, I did my research before trying to remove the pedals and my left or drive side pedal should be removed anti-clockwise if I understood the guide I was following.

Comment: It's the normal righty-tighty/lefty-loosey for the right pedal, and backwards that for the left.  You unscrew the left pedal by turning it CLOCKWISE.

Comment: I seem to be getting my left and rights mixed up but I have an issue with my drive side pedal.  According to this guide, I should be loosing it anti-clockwise:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFbSBG7jMzY

Comment: Yep, on most bikes the right side is the drive side.

Comment: Ah, my mistake on the calling the right the left. +1 I learned something

Comment: I had to think about it a little bit, too.  I spend too much time looking at bikes upside down.

Comment: I don’t think a pedal can be cross threaded and screwed so far in.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - It's amazing what people can do if they're determined to do it.  Many times the left pedal is screwed into the right side and vice-versa.

Comment: Can you post a pick of the pedals on the other side of the crank. It does not look cross threaded to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point the damage is done and the only options are to leave it as is or remove the pedal and heli-coil the crank arm. There are a few scenarios that can play out in this situation. The worst case is the pedal backs out unexpectedly, you loose control, crash and get hurt. I would think this unlikely as it has been like this for a year. I would use some Loctite 290 applied to the exposed end of the pedal axle. This type of product is a wicking compound. It will travel down the threads of the mounted pedal and lock it in place. If you are lucky the pedal won't back-out and it won't be an issue until the pedal or crank needs replacement. At that point the pedal threads are likely destroyed. If you decide to heli-coil the crank arm you could do it yourself, how ever the cost of the drill,tap and coils make it an expensive repair. It is likely more cost effective to have a local shop handle it.

Comment: Thanks @mikes,  I think the right answer is for me to take it to a LBS when I'm in the vicinity of one and see what they have to say.  You gave me a few options though that I can bring to the table.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the answer, but its possible your pedal threads are simply different lengths, or that your cranks are slightly different thicknesses.

There may even be a washer on one side but not on the other side - think of TA cranks which required the washer else they would split over time.

**TESTING**

When you ride, does the "bad" pedal corkscrew around under your foot?  Or is the pedal completely flat and normal feeling?   If its the latter, you just have a tight pedal, if its the former then its definitely cross threadded.

Comment: I mentioned before that the pedal feels fine to me but I wouldn't classifly myself as a advanced rider by any means.  So I might be missing something in translation.  Again, I think the solution is to go to the LBS and see what they have to say.